# HttpClient hangs on GetAsync when making many web requests to localhost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, authorization, dotnet-httpclient

I'm having the below issue when calling `api/Values/Test?times={x}`. The issue doesn't occur when `x` is 1, 2, ..., but the web request times out when it reaches 9, 10, and so on.
As you can see, the `Test` endpoint will make a web request to `EndPoint` `x` times (excuse the pointless method bodies, they'll do more meaningful things in practice):

```
public class ValuesController:  System.Web.Http.ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<object> Test(int times)
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
        for (var i = 0; i < times; i++)
        {
            //Make web request to the `EndPoint` method below
            var task = new ApiRequestBuilder<int>("https://localhost:44301/api/Values/EndPoint")
                .GetAsync();
            tasks.Add(task);
        }
        return await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
    } 

    [HttpGet]
    [CustomAuthorise]//This makes a web request to `AuthEndPoint` (below)
    public int EndPoint()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public bool AuthEndPoint()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

(**NB** see below for what `ApiRequestBuilder` is)

The problem, however, isn't `EndPoint` being hit `x` times, it's the `CustomAuthorise` attribute, which makes a further web request, that is the problem:

```
public class CustomAuthoriseAttribute : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await this.AuthoriseAsync(actionContext);
        if (!result)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }
    }

    public virtual async Task<bool> AuthoriseAsync(HttpActionContext context)
    {
        //***********HANGING HERE************
        //var result= await new ApiRequestBuilder<bool>("https://www.example.com")
        var result= await new ApiRequestBuilder<bool>("https://localhost:44301/Values/AuthEndPoint")
            .GetAsync();

        return result;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've commented out the route `"https://www.example.com"`. When I set the url to something that isn't `localhost`, a can spam that web request (by setting `x` to a large number) however much I want.

`ApiRequestBuilder` is a helper for making web requests via a `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` (version `4.0.0.0`, .NETframework `v4.5.1`), that serializes the response to the generic type parameter you give it.

```
public class ApiRequestBuilder<T> 
{
    protected string Url => Uri?.AbsoluteUri;
    protected Uri Uri;
    protected readonly HttpClient Client;

    public ApiRequestBuilder(string url) 
    {
        Uri = new Uri(url);
        var client = new HttpClient()
        {
            BaseAddress = this.Uri,
            //Set timeout so replicating this issue itn't a pain
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
        };
        this.Client = client;       
    }

    public async Task<T> GetAsync()
    {
        var response = await this.Client.GetAsync(this.Url);
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseContent);
    }
}
```

Things I've tried:

- Have a `using` statement for each use of `HttpClient` in `ApiRequestBuilder` - still hangs.
- Await each `Task` in the for loop in `ValuesController.Test` - this works, but does not solve my problem, as in practice I'm trying to simulate concurrency for using my custom auth attribute.

Potentially useful:

- I'm running local IIS on port `44301`, the maximum concurrent connections is massive - 4294967295.
- Like I said, changing the url from `localhost` to something like `example.com` when authorising, fixes the issue, which isolates the issue to something being wrong with my local setup

Does anyone know why using web request in authorise attributes seems hang with concurrency using `localhost` rather than using a url out there in the big wide world?

**UPDATE**

Running `netstat -n` at the point of hanging (I removed the timeout for this so I could look at what the TCP connections were doing). For every web request in progress that was seemingly blocked I had the following:

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
TCP    [::1]:44301            [::1]:44728            CLOSE_WAIT
TCP    [::1]:44728            [::1]:44301            FIN_WAIT_2
```

With the help of [this](https://kb.iu.edu/d/ajmi), it seems like the server has asked the client to exit, the clients acknowledged it, but they're both hanging (client isn't closing?).

Answer (score 1):

Could be that too many clients are being created and causing a known issue with socket exhaustion.

Refrence [YOU'RE USING HTTPCLIENT WRONG AND IT IS DESTABILIZING YOUR SOFTWARE](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Using a single static client should potentially solve this problem

```
public class ApiRequestBuilder<T>  {
    protected string Url => Uri?.AbsoluteUri;
    protected Uri Uri;
    static HttpClient Client = new HttpClient() {
        //Set timeout so replicating this issue itn't a pain
        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
    };

    public ApiRequestBuilder(string url) {
        Uri = new Uri(url);        
    }

    public async Task<T> GetAsync() {
        var response = await Client.GetAsync(this.Url);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: agree with this answer. For more information you can look at [HttpClient Issues](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).

Comment: @user3785553 yep I've seen that article as well. Will include it in answer for reference.

Comment: @Nkosi thanks for your help with this. Unfortunately changing the `HttpClient` to a static property didn't fix the issue. If that were the case, I would expect the socket exhaustion issue you mentioned to also be an issue when using "www.example.com", rather than `localhost`

Comment: HttpClient has limits, had this myself when I used postman on my local machine for testing 1000 calls without interval pause. Seems like sockets can get clodded. Maybe the new httpclientfactory mechanism in .net core 2.1 / 2.2 can help out

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for . Net core 2.1 but it may explain your issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests